# why i can't get the result of appending list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
d={}
for i in range (5):
    d['key']=i
    lst.append(d)
print(lst) 
>>>[{'key': 4}, {'key': 4}, {'key': 4}, {'key': 4}, {'key': 4}]
```

Why i didn't got this result plz  :`>>>[{'key': 0}, {'key': 1}, {'key': 2}, {'key': 3}, {'key': 4}]` ?

Comment: You're appending references to the same underlying dictionary to the list. Try moving `d={}` into the loop.

Comment: you could do ```lst.append(d.copy())``` instead

Comment: Just do `lst.append({"key": i})` there's no need for `d`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work:

```py
lst = []
for i in range(1, 6):
    lst.append({"key", i})
print(lst)
```

The problem was that you are appending the variable `d` to `lst`. the value of `lst` is now `[d, d, d, d, d]`. When printing, this evaluates to `d`'s current value, which happens to be `{'key', 4}`. My code appends the value of d to the list without creating `d`. This is at least my interpretation of this. Could be wrong.